# Read multiple filenames glob (tensorflow), Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to import the filenames which include "ABC" and the filenames which include "XYZ". At the moment I am only able to read all files which contain "ABC". How can I also include files which contain "XYZ" in the file name?

```
filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob((GCS_OUTPUT + "*ABC*"))

dataset4 = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=AUTO)
dataset4 = dataset4.with_options(option_no_order)
dataset4 = dataset4.map(read_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
dataset4 = dataset4.shuffle(300)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the regex `"*ABC*"` to `"(*ABC*|*DEF*)"`